# Dangling "There" Reference

Tags: relative-pronouns

There might be a problem [here](http://news.yahoo.com/us-bigger-russian-artillery-moving-ukraine-172046809.html):

> Warren said the U.S. has seen no indication of Ukraine firing back into Russia, and there have been no reports of civilian casualties. He said the number of Russian troops ***along the border*** continues to slowly but steadily increase. Close to 12,000 are ***there*** now.

Is "there" dangling, because it seems to refer to the areas along the border between Ukraine and Russia, but no explicit reference to such exist in the paragraph?  Would editing the second sentence in the paragraph like this:

> ...He said the number of Russian troops ***in areas*** *along the border* continues to slowly but steadily increase...

be better?

Answer (score 2):

It is not dangling. The "there" refers to a previously-mentioned place: "the border".

Comment: Does that mean I could write:  "There are at least two cats ***at a spot behind the fence***.  A third cat might be ***there*** too." and then delete "*at a spot*" without causing problem, even though "*there*" refers to "*a spot behind the fence*", not "*behind the fence*"?

Comment: @meatie, "There are at least two cats behind the fence. A third cat might be there too." Yes, I don't see any problem with that. "Behind the fence" is enough to identify the location.

Comment: But "*behind the fence*" is not explicit enough.

Comment: _at a spot behind the fence_ works, too. why do you think _behind the fence_ is not explicit enough?